# How to go about solving: 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes '

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, plotly, plotly-dash

**Context:**

My code (goal) explained:

- If from the list 'listCoords' the values from the hour-column is
  between 1 and 5
- AND from the Threat-column the value is equal to '3'. --> output the color 'red'.
- ELSE, output 'np.append(np.insert(listCoords.index.hour, 0, 0), 23)' (which is an
  array list of amount of observation-frequencies per hour).
- np.append(np.insert(listCoords.index.hour, 0, 0), 23) --> is then considered by my colour-range and each dot gets not the color 'red', but rather gets a color I have specified in an hour-range.

**The code works if I have it like this**:

```
color=np.append(np.insert(listCoords.index.hour, 0, 0), 23)),
```

I want to specify from that list the dots that meet my explained two conditions and mark them **red**.

**The code also works if I do**:

```
color=np.where(((listCoords.index.hour >= 1) & (listCoords.index.hour < 5)) & (listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 'red', 'blue'),
```

But I don't want the general plots to be blue, I want them to get a color correlating to the hour they were detected in.

**my indented code snipper:**:

```
color=np.where(((listCoords.index.hour >= 1) & (listCoords.index.hour < 5)) & (listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 'red', np.append(np.insert(listCoords.index.hour, 0, 0), 23)),
```

**But this outputs error message:** - I don't understand this message or how to solve it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/DSP_Frontend/app.py", line 509, in update_graph
    color=np.where(((listCoords.index.hour >= 1) & (listCoords.index.hour < 5)) & (listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 'red', np.append(np.insert(listCoords.index.hour, 0, 0), 23)), #
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in where

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (241,) () (243,)
```

> **My question**: How can I solve this issue?

**my overall code context**:

```
return go.Figure(
        data=[
            # Data for all observations based on date and time
            Scattermapbox(
                lat=listCoords["Lat"],
                lon=listCoords["Lon"],
                mode="markers",
                hoverinfo="text + lat + lon",
                text=np.append(np.insert(listCoords.index.hour, 0, 0), 23), #listCoords.index.hour,
                marker=dict(
                    showscale=True,
                    # the color is decided by the time of detection.
                    # color=np.append(np.insert(listCoords.index.hour, 0, 0), 23),
                    color=np.where(((listCoords.index.hour >= 1) & (listCoords.index.hour < 5)) & (listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 'red', 'blue'), #
                    opacity=np.where(((listCoords.index.hour >= 1) & (listCoords.index.hour < 5)) & (listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 0.1, 0.6), 
                    size=np.where(((listCoords.index.hour >= 1) & (listCoords.index.hour < 5)) & (listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 80, 7),
                    colorscale=[
                        [0, "#F4EC15"],
                        [0.04167, "#DAF017"],
                        [0.0833, "#BBEC19"],
                        [0.125, "#9DE81B"],
                        [0.1667, "#80E41D"],
                        [0.2083, "#66E01F"],
                        [0.25, "#4CDC20"],
                        [0.292, "#34D822"],
                        [0.333, "#24D249"],
                        [0.375, "#25D042"],
                        [0.4167, "#26CC58"],
                        [0.4583, "#28C86D"],
                        [0.50, "#29C481"],
                        [0.54167, "#2AC093"],
                        [0.5833, "#2BBCA4"],
                        [1.0, "#613099"],
                    ],
                    colorbar=dict(
                        title="Time of<br>Day",
                        x=0.93,
                        xpad=0,
                        nticks=24,
                        tickfont=dict(color="#d8d8d8"),
                        titlefont=dict(color="#d8d8d8"),
                        thicknessmode="pixels",
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

**---------------------EDIT 1---------------------**

I have added the following line to my code to inspect the shapes:

```
    shape1 = (listCoords.index.hour >= 1) & (listCoords.index.hour < 5)
    shape2 = (listCoords['Threat'] == '3')
    shape3 =  np.append(np.insert(listCoords.index.hour, 0, 0), 23)

    print('shape 1: ', shape1, ' shape 2: ', shape2, ' shape 3: ', shape3)
```

This outputs the following:

```
shape 1:  [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False]  

shape 2:  Date/Time
2019-06-02 04:00:00    False
2019-06-02 04:05:00    False
2019-06-02 04:10:00    False
2019-06-02 04:15:00    False
2019-06-02 04:20:00    False
                       ...  
2019-06-02 16:25:00    False
2019-06-02 16:30:00    False
2019-06-02 16:35:00    False
2019-06-02 16:40:00    False
2019-06-02 16:45:00    False

Name: Threat, Length: 241, dtype: bool  
shape 3:  [ 0  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5
      5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6
      6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7
      7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
      8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
      9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12
     12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
     13 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14
     14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
     15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
     16 16 23]
```

So apparently there seems to be a significant difference between the shapes (241,) and (243,)

Comment: You have a lot of operations going on in that statement. [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  The shapes of your comparisons aren't compatible.  You might want to make separate arrays, one for each comparison so they can be inspected, then sequentially `and` those making more separate arrays so they can be inspected.  It isn't clear from your question if you are expecting a 1d result or an nd result or what your logic is.. A **minimal** example of the input and expected output would help. [mcve].

Comment: @wwii Yes, so rule is that dimensions are compared from the last to the first. Any dimensions that do not match must be stretched to become equally sized. However, according to the previous rule, only dimensions of size 1 can stretch. This means that some shapes cannot broadcast and Numpy will give you an error. Is there not any way to reshape any of the operands intermediately? Might .dot or .reshape not help? If so, might you know how one could possibly go about this?

Comment: If you look at that Broadcasting link in my first comment it explains the process, but it isn't clear what your expectation is. From the TraceBack, one of the shapes is `()` which is kinda weird.

Comment: On the `cond` argument, the shape is determined by `listCoords.index` `(241,)`.  But for the 3rd argument, you have taken array of that size and added 2 elements (with the insert and append).  So now it is too long to work with the condition.  Was that (243,) shape intentional?

Comment: But I don't think your additions help with the immediate problem.  You can't use a condition of one size and B value that is larger.

Comment: `shape1` is the result of applying the `&` operator to two series, and the result is a 1d numpy array.  `shape3` is also the result of apply numpy operations, and is also an array, though with 2 more elements.  `shape2` is a pandas Series, with a different display.  `shape2.values` would appear more like `shape1`, an array.

Comment: What do you get for `listCoords.shape`? And why do you think you need to insert a `0` and append `23` to the Dataframe index?

Comment: @wwii it is (241, 3). The 0 and the 23 comes from my histogram. Which shows 24 hours. And each bar represents the frequency of observations per hour in one day.

Comment: … but why do you think you need to do that? You should just be using your data.

Comment: Please do not continually morph/mutate your question each time you get a little further along.  Ask a question, get an answer, ask another question... Seems like you need to spend some time with the documentation that last error message is pretty self explanatory..

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265794/should-i-accept-an-answer-while-still-there-are-more-errors-and-lead-to-new-erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

First I removed the append/insert because the 0 and 23 were not needed. This solved the 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes' issue. This brought the second shape back from (243,) to (241,).

But now with the following piece applied:

```
color=np.where((listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 'red', listCoords.index.hour)
```

It outputted a new error:

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'color' property of scattermapbox.marker
        Invalid elements include: ['4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4']

    The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as:
      - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
      - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
      - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
      - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
      - A named CSS color:
            aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
            beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue,
            blueviolet, brown, burlywood, cadetblue,
            chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerblue....
```

To solve this, I altered the colorscale by saying [0, "#FF0000"] (meaning 0 equals red).

Subsequently, I said that if ('Threat == 3' give 0) else give regular colours.

My new code (only parts that have been updated):

```
    red = 0
    mycolors = np.where((listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), red, listCoords.index.hour)
    print(mycolors)
```

and

```
  color=np.array(mycolors, int),
                colorscale=[
                    [0, "#FF0000"],
                    [0.04167, "#DAF017"],
                    [0.0833, "#BBEC19"],
                    [0.125, "#9DE81B"],
                    [0.1667, "#80E41D"],
                    [0.2083, "#66E01F"],
                    [0.25, "#4CDC20"],
                    [0.292, "#34D822"],
                    [0.333, "#24D249"],
                    [0.375, "#25D042"],
                    [0.4167, "#26CC58"],
                    [0.4583, "#28C86D"],
                    [0.50, "#29C481"],
                    [0.54167, "#2AC093"],
                    [0.5833, "#2BBCA4"],
                    [1.0, "#613099"],
                ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on your `where` problem, with a simpler case:

A 1d array, and condition:

```
In [37]: x = np.arange(10)                                                                       
In [38]: cond = (x>3)&(x<8)                                                                      
In [39]: y = np.append(np.insert(x,0,-1),100)                                                    
In [40]: cond.shape                                                                              
Out[40]: (10,)
In [41]: y.shape                                                                                 
Out[41]: (12,)
In [42]: y                                                                                       
Out[42]: array([ -1,   0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9, 100])
```

We get your error when we try to use a `cond` of size 10, with a value `y` of size 12.

```
In [43]: np.where(cond, -1, y)                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-13267573c792> in <module>
----> 1 np.where(cond, -1, y)

<__array_function__ internals> in where(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) () (12,)
```

We could expand the cond to size 12:

```
In [44]: cond1 = np.append(np.insert(cond,0,False),False)                                        
In [45]: cond1                                                                                   
Out[45]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
       False, False, False])
In [46]: np.where(cond1, -1, y)                                                                  
Out[46]: array([ -1,   0,   1,   2,   3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,   8,   9, 100])
In [47]: _.shape                                                                                 
Out[47]: (12,)
```

Note that the result has size 12

Your original where works because it is using the size 10 cond with two scalar values:

```
In [48]: np.where(cond, -1, 100)                                                                 
Out[48]: array([100, 100, 100, 100,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1, 100, 100])
In [49]:
```

Comment: Sir, could you please refer to my EDIT2 I just applied